# Can't store properly for sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I would like to set if statement to control the data storage in sqlite. However, the data will be stored all or none that the if statement can not block incorrect data. Please give me some hints. Thanks.

```
public void luggageCheck (String ncode, String luggage1, String luggage2, String luggage3){

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    if (luggage1 !=  " " ){
        db.addContact(new Luggage(ncode, luggage1, "luggage")); 
    }
    if (luggage2 !=  " "){
        db.addContact(new Luggage(ncode, luggage2, "luggage"));
    }
    if (luggage3 !=  " "){
        db.addContact(new Luggage(ncode, luggage3, "luggage"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in Java are compared with the method "equals", not with operators

That means, your code should be:

```
if (!luggage1.equals(" ")){
    db.addContact(new Luggage(ncode, luggage1, "luggage")); 
}
if (!luggage2.equals(" ")){
    db.addContact(new Luggage(ncode, luggage2, "luggage"));
}
if (!luggage3.equals(" ")){
    db.addContact(new Luggage(ncode, luggage3, "luggage"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. However, I would like ask that what is the different between string.compareTo() and !string.equal()? because I use the compareTo works in the previous coding? Thanks so much.

Comment: compareTo is comparing the two objects, and returns the result(0 = objects are equal, less then 0 = the first object is smaller(lexicographically) then the second, more then 0 = the first object is bigger(lexicographically) then the second). equals returns boolean value if the objects are equal(in this context string objects)